# How are the Nitya Srauta Yajnas like Agnihotra done while travelling?

Tags: vedas, purva-mimamsa, sruti, mimamsa, katyayana-srauta-sutra

According to Srutis once someone kindles the Tretagni must perform the Agnihotra and the fortnightly Darsapurnameshti homas daily till the death of either husband or wife or till sannyasa.

1. My question is does this mean the Nitya Agnihotris do not go travelling even for teertha yatras?
2. Some sources say in the absence of a husband the wife can perform the Agnihotra, what if both husband and wife travel?
3. Were the Pandavas, Sri Krishna, and Dronacharya nitya agnihotris, how were they doing it during travelling?
4. If the agnihotri changes the residence can he change the tretagni vedi and rekindle it in new place of residence?
5. During the travelling can the tretagni vedi constructed exactly at the time of sunrise and sunset for Agnihotra?